# Mesh-wifi: change parent if RSSI is lower than threshold

Tags: wifi, esp32, rssi, esp-idf, mesh-network

I'm working with several ESP32 connected in a wifi mesh.

Now I have 5 nodes (`N1`, `N2`, `N3`, `N4`, `N5`) connected in this way:

```
Root(N1)

|

L2 ( N2,N3,N4 )

|

L3 ( N5)
```

Regarding position and distance:

[image: image mesh]

I thought that `N3`, `N4` will be connected to `N5`.
I found that is it possible to set variables in order to tell nodes to change the parent if RSSI is greater or lower than a reference.
Here is the [link to esp-idf](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/esp_wifi/include/esp_mesh_internal.h)

I think I have to set:

```
typedef struct {
    int duration_ms;   /* parent weak RSSI monitor duration, if the RSSI continues to be weak during this duration_ms,
                          device will search for a new parent. */
    int cnx_rssi;      /* RSSI threshold for keeping a good connection with parent.
                          If set a value greater than -120 dBm, a timer will be armed to monitor parent RSSI at a period time of duration_ms. */
    int select_rssi;   /* RSSI threshold for parent selection. It should be a value greater than switch_rssi. */
    int switch_rssi;   /* Disassociate with current parent and switch to a new parent when the RSSI is greater than this set threshold. */
    int backoff_rssi;  /* RSSI threshold for connecting to the root */
} mesh_switch_parent_t;
```

`select_rssi` and `switch_rssi`, correct?

Do I also have to set:

```
typedef struct {
    int high;
    int medium;
    int low;
} mesh_rssi_threshold_t;
```

How are these variables related?

Comment: anyone has some hints?